# "Rigid" Riemannian metrics

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

What do we mean when we say that a Riemannian metric $g$ is rigid?
For example, the Eguchi-Hanson metric is rigid as an Einstein metric.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that all other metrics with this property are isometric to the given metric.

For example the Mostow rigidity theorem says that all hyperbolic metrics on a closed n-Manifold are isometric to each other, if $n\ge 3$. So the hyperbolic metric is rigid in this case.

On the other Hand, hyperbolic metrics on 2-manifolds are not rigid. There is a whole modulo space of them (Teichmüller theory).